# Image processing is too slow when creating image filters

Tags: android, image-processing, opengl-es-2.0, renderscript

I'm developing an Android image editor app. I tried to use pure Java to create image filters but is too slow! I heard something about OPENGL ES 2 (The Android's EffectFactory class use it) and RenderScript but I really haven't found documentation or tutorials that say "to process images e.g. apply image filters, you need to do this!".

I'm using this code:

```
public static Bitmap doColorFilter(Bitmap src, double red, double green, double blue) {
    // image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    // create output bitmap
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    // color information
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;

    // scan through all pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            // get pixel color
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            // apply filtering on each channel R, G, B
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = (int)(Color.red(pixel) * red);
            G = (int)(Color.green(pixel) * green);
            B = (int)(Color.blue(pixel) * blue);
            // set new color pixel to output bitmap
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }

    // return final image
    return bmOut;
}}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have done..Dont expect SO members to do coding for your ideas..

Answer (score 0):

I hope [android-jhlabs](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/) will be helpfull . It has many image filtering algorithms that you can use.
Here is the filter usage details: [FilterUsage](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/wiki/FilterUsage)

And here is another usefull library for image processing:
[android-lib-magick](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick)

Java port of [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) - [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) has also many image processing classes that you can use.

Here is the image processing tutorial that I myself recommend you to follow:
[Image Processing Tutorial](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/)

THANX !!!

Comment: i used the code of the last tutorial on my app. Its so good but is so slow! hehehe

Comment: Playing with bitmap is a slow operation. Also use AsyncTask for background processsing.

Answer (score 0):

> What you are searching for is very wide concept , Its not like that i
>   will post my answer and you get all what you needed .

I found some very good example represented by Stanford Uni. about image processing concept.
http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/

I hope this will help you get started but as i said its long way to go !